# summing by rows sql

Tags: sql, function

I attempted to do it using the analytical function, but it appears that I did so improperly...
How can I receive the output from the table I've been given?

```
CREATE TABLE rides (
  ride_id INT, 
  driver_id INT, 
  ride_in_kms INT, 
  ride_fare FLOAT, 
  ride_date DATE
);
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (1, 1, 3, 4.45, "2016-05-16");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (2, 1, 4, 8.46, "2016-05-16");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (3, 2, 6, 11.9, "2016-05-16");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (4, 3, 3, 6.76, "2016-05-16");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (5, 2, 6, 13.55, "2016-05-16");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (6, 4, 3, 4.91, "2016-05-20");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (7, 1, 7, 16.77, "2016-05-20");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (8, 3, 9, 16.18, "2016-05-20");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (9, 2, 3, 6.07, "2016-05-20");
INSERT INTO rides VALUES (10, 4, 4, 6.25, "2016-05-20");
```

Output result

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database?  Use triple backtick to format code.  I did it twice for you and it was blown away by your edits.

Comment: Please format the text instead of using images.

Answer (score 0):

The general gist is to use an expression within the `sum()` to operate on the correct rows:

```
select
  driver_id,
  sum(case when ride_date = "2016-05-16" then ride_in_kms else 0 end) `KMS_MAY_16`,
  sum(case when ride_date = "2016-05-20" then ride_in_kms else 0 end) `KMS_MAY_20`
from
   group by driver_id;
```

The particular syntax available, and how to express the column label depends on what database you are using.

Comment: i tried to use case when, but i got null when it does not satisfy the condition

Comment: Did you try the exact query that I gave you?  The else part would be significant.